# Is there any way to tell if people have opened a Google Drive document that you have shared?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I sent out links (read-only) to a number of people and am curious if there is a way to see whether people are actually going out and viewing that document.

I understand it likely won't have names for everyone/anyone that looks at it, but I'd be interested at least in knowing how many "hits" it got to make sure that at least some of those I sent it too actually looked at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page describes a method to do so.

[Track Visitors To Google Docs; Know When People Open & Read Your Documents](http://www.labnol.org/internet/office/track-google-docs-visitors-know-when-document-read-opened/3397/)

It suggests to add a blank image to the document which can then be counted using statcounter.com

Comment: It looks like editing the HTML of a document is no longer supported, and there does not appear to be a menu option for inserting a gadget in a document either.  Gadgets are however supported in spreadsheets.

Comment: I posted an updated answer basing on Paul's to workaround the "no HTML editing is there any more": http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/google-docs-is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-people-have-opened-a-document-that-you/49555#49555 (moderators here suggested me to post as a new answer rather than to edit Paul's)

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work at all any more. Now Google Docs Presentation seems to retrieve image-by-URL once upon inserting, and therefore no pixel-based web site tracking tools work at all.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2013-Oct-4:** Looks like this doesn't work anymore. Now Google Docs Presentation seems to retrieve image-by-URL once upon inserting, and therefore no website tracking tools work anymore.

**Update 2014-Jan-11:** Seems to be working for Sheets but not Docs

---

Any web site analytics tool can help. For example, www.statcounter.com (it's free):

1. Go to [statcounter.com](http://statcounter.com) and register for a free account.
2. Under “Install Code”, choose the following options:

   `Invisible Counter -> Google Pages -> HTML only counter.`

   Statcounter will now generate some HTML code enclosed in a `<div>` tag. Strip everything except the URL in the IMG tag, it looks like this:

   `http://c46.statcounter.com/3732481/0/e1fdff4b/1/`
3. Open the Google Docs document that you want to track.
4. In Google Docs menu, choose: `Insert > Image > By URL > Paste an image URL here:`. Insert the above URL.

Currently, it works at least for Documents, Spreadsheets and Presentations.

---

*This answer is based on [Paul Rowland's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/google-docs-is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-people-have-opened-a-document-that-you/12805#12805) and [the blog post he linked to](http://www.labnol.org/internet/office/track-google-docs-visitors-know-when-document-read-opened/3397/).*

Answer (score 0):

On [August 21, 2018](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/08/activity-dashboard-available-all-GSuite.html) Google launched for all the [activity dashboard](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739?hl=en) for Google editors (documents, forms, slides and spreadsheets) but it could not show what you are expecting as users could disable showing their activity and G Suite administrators have administrator settings that affect how this feature works for their users.

Anyway, this could be helpful in certain scenarios especially if you share documents with a group of users that have the view history turned on.